# Mount point does not exist (Even though it does)

Tags: shared-folders, nas, mountpoint

I added these lines to my /etc/fstab:

```
//10.23.83.7/AIP ~/Shares/AIP cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

When I run sudo mount -a I get:

```
mount: mount point ~/Shares/AIP does not exist
```

It does exist though and I can cd ~/Shares/AIP just fine. I also tried it with /Shares/AIP and /aip/Shares/AIP (aip is my username).

What is the correct way to enter this path? I am trying to mount several folders from a NAS.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/fstab` is parsed as root. This means that `~/Shares/AIP` is expanded to `/root/Shares/AIP` (assuming you haven't changed the home directory of the user. The correct path would be `/home/aip/Shares/AIP`.

Therefore the whole correct line would be:

```
//10.23.83.7/AIP /home/aip/Shares/AIP cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

## To prove this:

```
sudo su
cd ~/Shares/AIP
```

It should say it dosen't exist.

To prove that it is parsed as root, try mounting something as a normal user. It won't work.